# Check in which array a string is included

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some arrays like this and a simple string:

```
 const filename = 'test.jpg';
 let fileExtension = filename.split('.').pop();
 const images = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'];
 const pdf = ['pdf'];
```

I need to check in which array the string is included and return the name of that array. I have tried something like this:

```
switch (fileExtension) {
  case images.includes(fileExtension):
    return 'image'; 
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

I've tried to use `Array.includes` as it returns `true` or `false`, but I think it is not possible.

Do you have any simple solution? Thanks. :-) Also there can be more than two arrays.

Comment: Don't use a `switch`, use a good old `if..else`.

Comment: Ok, but I will have more than two arrays :(

Comment: If you use an object like `{ image: ['png', ...], pdf: [...], ... }`, you can use a loop…

Comment: Ok, thats also good solution, can you write answer

Answer (score 2):

If the aim is to map extension to a file type, the better static structure "maps" extensions to types. No array, no loop...

```js
const ext2Type = { 'png' : 'image', 'xls' : 'MS Excel', 'jpg' : 'image' } // etc
const filename = 'test.jpg';
let fileExtension = filename.split('.').pop();
const type = ext2Type[fileExtension];
console.log(type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that ?

```js
const filename = 'test.jpg';
let fileExtension = filename.split('.').pop();
const images = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'];
const pdf = ['pdf'];

const searchedArrays = {images, pdf};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(searchedArrays )) {
  if (value.includes(fileExtension) {
    return key;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
 let bins = { images: [...], docs: [...] }
 let ext = 'pdf'

 function detectBin( ext ) {
      return bins.images.includes(ext) ? 'image' : ( bins.docs.includes( ext) ? 'document' : 'unknown' );
  }

 let bin = detectBin( ext );
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that's not exactly what you're asking for, but it seems to me like your approach is a slight overkill. Unless you really need those arrays to be dynamic - a static function which could be reused seems like a better solution.

```js
const getExtensionType = (filename) => {
  const ext = filename.split('.').pop()

  if (['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'].includes(ext)) {
    return 'image'
  }

  if (ext === 'pdf') {
    return 'pdf'
  }

  return null
}

console.log(getExtensionType('hello-world.jpg'))
// image

console.log(getExtensionType('hello-world.pdf'))
// pdf
```